# Why does Gradle need to get online so often?

Tags: android, gradle

I was wondering what it is that makes Gradle sync dependencies online so often. Once the requested dependency is downloaded, why can't I use Gradle without an internet connection. 
I know there's an off line mode option in Android Studio, but that's not really what I want, I have no problem with it downloading dependencies when I request them, it's the consecutive dependency "syncing" that I find bothersome.
So, my question would be, why does it need to sync dependencies so often when I'm already asking for a framework's specific version number?
(the syncing would make sense if I did something like 2.1.+, but I'm not doing that)

Thanks in advance

Comment: usually gradle does not need to sync dependencies if you have only fixed versions in your build. It could be something implemented in android studio as studio checks if a newer version is in the repositories etc. Gradle itself doesn't do that out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

How often is it syncing? I understood, that it's "only" syncing once per day.

> Gradle will once per day (by default) connect to the artifact repository to see if there is a more recent version.

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released

Other than the source of the quote I never found a reason to those constant new version checks.

Best,
Schnaps